# Avoid certain Tor exit nodes by IP

Tags: tor

Is there way to tell Tor to avoid certain exit nodes? I have a problem where a certain exit node IP is blocked by  a service I'm trying to reach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The next hop inside a Tor bouncing is a decision made by the nodes using decision-based algorithms and not by the users connecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can. Assuming that the `torrc` settings actually work and are not just there to give use a false sense of security:

```
StrictNodes 1

ExcludeExitNodes {enter-country-code},{??}

ExcludeNodes {enter-country-code},{??}
```

The question is rather: Is it safe to trust any "security" product coming from the EU or CANZUK? If you don't know what I mean, read up on Crypto AG (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto_AG) and 1G/2G/3G architecture (https://jstor.org/stable/pdf/26487508.pdf).

You can look up the country codes [here](https://b3rn3d.herokuapp.com/blog/2014/03/05/tor-country-codes)!